# Importing very large dataset into h2o from sqlite

Tags: r, sqlite, h2o

I have a database of about 500G. It comprises of 16 tables, each containing 2 or 3 column (first column can be discarded) and 1,375,328,760 rows. I need all the tables to be joined as one dataframe in h2o as they are needed for running a prediction in an XGB model. I have tried to convert the individual sql tables into the h2o environment using as.h2o, and h2o.cbind them 2 or 3 tables at a time, until they are one dataset. However, I get this "GC overhead limit exceeded: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError", after converting 4 tables.
Is there a way around this?
My machine specs are 124G RAM, OS (Rhel 7.8), Root(1tb), Home(600G) and 2TB external HDD.
The model is run on this local machine and the max_mem_size is set at 100G. The details of the code are below.

````
library(data.table)
library(h2o)          
h2o.init(
  nthreads=14,          
  max_mem_size = "100G")    
h2o.removeAll() 

setwd("/home/stan/Documents/LUR/era_aq")

l1.hex <- as.h2o(d2)
l2.hex <- as.h2o(lai)
test_l1.hex <-h2o.cbind(l1.hex,l2.hex[,-1])
h2o.rm (l1.hex,l2.hex)
l3.hex <- as.h2o(lu100)
l4.hex <- as.h2o(lu1000)
test_l2.hex <-h2o.cbind(l3.hex,l4.hex[,-1])
h2o.rm(l3.hex,l4.hex)
l5.hex <- as.h2o(lu1250)
l6.hex <- as.h2o(lu250)
test_l3.hex <-h2o.cbind(l5.hex,l6.hex[,-1])
h2o.rm(l5.hex,l6.hex)
l7.hex <- as.h2o(pbl)
l8.hex <- as.h2o(msl)
test_l4.hex <-h2o.cbind(l7.hex,l8.hex[,-1])
h2o.rm(ll7.hex,l8.hex)

test.hex <-h2o.cbind(test_l1.hex,test_l2.hex[,-1],test_l3.hex[,-1],test_l4.hex[,-1])
test <- test.hex[,-1]
test[1:3,]```
````

Comment: You appear to remove  *l6.hex* but use it in a later `cbind`. Also, you remove first column on some but not all objects. Where do *d2*, *lai*, etc. derive? Try avoiding all these separate objects. How does SQLite factor in here?

Comment: Based on your description, the H2O-3 rule of thumb says you need 20x more memory.  500GB data x 4 == 2 TB memory.  It’s no surprise you hit OOM.  I suggest you try a big machine, or a cluster of big machines, in the cloud.

Comment: @Parfait Thanks pointing that out the error for l6.hex, it was a layover from an earlier version of the code that I missed. There's another section about sqlite which made the code too long so I skipped it since all it did was basically connect to the DB and the extract tables.

Comment: @TomKraljevic Thanks for your suggestion, but I don't think I can afford to do any of those at this time, hence my trying to find any workaround the OOM problem.

Comment: Thanks for answering first and last. However, what about middle question: where do `d2`, `lai`, etc. derive? Are these data tables/frames read from csv or sqlite? Also, why is first column removed for some and not all objects?

Comment: @Parfait. Those variables (d2, lai, etc) are tables derived from the sqlite. Actually, at the end of the binding process, all first columns are removed. The removal at different stages of the binding was to ensure that all the tables were all bound properly. I removed it when I no longer needed it.

Answer (score 2):

First, as Tom says in the comments, you're gonna need a bigger boat. H2O holds all data in memory, and generally you need 3 to 4x the data size to be able to do anything useful with it. A dataset of 500GB means you need the total memory of your cluster to be 1.5-2TB.

(H2O stores the data compressed, and I don't think sqlite does, in which case you might get away with only needing 1TB.)

Second, `as.h2o()` is an inefficient way to load big datasets. What will happen is your dataset is loaded into R's memory space, then it is saved to a csv file, then that csv file is streamed over TCP/IP to the H2O process.

So, the better way is to export directly from sqlite to a csv file. And then use `h2o.importFile()` to load that csv file into H2O.

`h2o.cbind()` is also going to involve a lot of copying. If you can find a tool or script to column-bind the csv files in advance of import, it might be more efficient. A quick search found [csvkit](https://csvkit.readthedocs.io/en/latest/), but I'm not sure if it needs to load the files into memory, or can do work with the files completely on disk.

Answer (score 1):

Since memory is a premium and all R runs in RAM, avoid storing large helper `data.table` and`h20` objects in your global environment. Consider setting up a function to build a list for compilation that temporary objects are removed when function is out of scope. Ideally, you build your `h2o` objects directly from file source:

```
# BUILD LIST OF H20 OBJECTS WITHOUT HELPER COPIES
h2o_list <- lapply(list_of_files, function(f) as.h2o(data.table::fread(f))[-1])
# h2o_list <- lapply(list_of_files, function(f) h2o.importFile(f)[-1])

# CBIND ALL H20 OBJECTS
test.h2o <- do.call(h2o.cbind, h2o_list)
```

Or even combine both lines with named function as opposed to anonymous function. Then, only final object remains after processing.

```
build_h2o <- function(f) as.h2o(data.table::fread(f))[-1])
# build_h2o <- function(f) h2o.importFile(f)[-1]

test.h2o <- do.call(h2o.cbind, lapply(list_of_files, build_h2o))
```

Extend function with `if` for some datasets that need to retain first column or not.

```
build_h2o <- function(f) {
   if (grepl("lai|lu1000|lu250|msl", f)) { tmp <- fread(f)[-1] }
   else { tmp <- fread(f) }

   return(as.h2o(tmp))
}
```

Finally, if possible, leverage `data.table` methods like `cbindlist`:

```
final_dt <- cbindlist(lapply(list_of_files, function(f) fread(f)[-1]))

test.h2o <- as.h2o(final_dt)

rm(final_dt)
gc()
```

Comment: Thanks for this suggestions. However, I wasn't able to load all 20 cols that was meant to be bound to form the new file. Is there another way to clear some of the data from the RAM during this process? I have tried to do this by dividing them into 4 parts in binding them in two steps but it still failed. Is there is way to write the data directly to the hard disk so I don't keep this data in the RAM?

Comment: Without knowing more of your fuller context or reproducible example, not sure if I can help more. Again, I advise to avoid holding helper copies in your global environment that take up memory like `d2`, `lai`, etc.. Here reads data directly from disk but can be changed for SQLite with `dbGetQuery` into `h2o`.